# Trivial established protocol for sending a single string message?

Tags: networking, protocols, file-transfer

I have two machines M1, M2 on a network, with processes P1, P2 running on each of these machines. (The process is a C++-compiled executable, but perhaps that's not very significant.) These processes can also open, listen and connect on ports if necessary.

I want P1 to send a single string to P2 - not super-short nor super-long (say, 1 KB to 100 KB). The string is made up of printable ASCII characters, nothing extraordinary.

Now, I can have P2 keep an open a TCP port and listen on it, and P1 connect to it using TCP, send the message, and close the connection - and this will work.

My question is: Is there an formally-established, extremely-simple protocol that is basically just what I described? It would be much simpler than TFTP, for example.